# What is a numerical method to solve IVP at irregular singular point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, singularity

I have tried to search for numerical method to solve IVP with irregular singular point but didn't find any.

What is the proper method I can use to solve such equations?

$$y''+\frac{y'}{x^2}+y=x^3+6x+3$$
With initial conditions
$$y(0)=0, y'(0)=0$$

Obviously, collocation method (which I know) won't work.

I'm not interested in this particular problem, it's only an example.

Comment: @Moo 1 is an ordinary point, I want to solve it at 0 which is irregular singular.

Comment: Maybe try to use $y(\epsilon)=0, y'(\epsilon)=0$ for some small number $\epsilon$, solve this problem and examine the case $\epsilon\to0?$

Comment: I wonder if if the paper referred to next addresses the OP question (and references therein): https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apnum.2019.09.006

Comment: @JCO thanks for your response, but the paper deals with regular singularity and I ask for irregular case.

Comment: @Mohamed Mostafa my apologies! Interesting topic! I found some papers (none recent): [1] https://www.jstor.org/stable/2653229. [2] https://doi.org/10.1137/0702018 [3] https://doi.org/10.1137/0702017.